# Challenge - Arduino returning multiple arrays

Tags: c++, c, arrays, arduino

Okay, in last few hours I was trying to make a lock with arduino

-There are 4 buttons, each one has number (1,2,3,4)
-you have 8 spaces for code

So I started with function that will change the password.
(b1s .... are button states)

The question is, is there way to do it more easily than converting every single part of array into int? Thank you, have a nice day!

```css
  int passwordCreate() {
    int x1[9];
    int x2[9];
    int x3[9];
    int x4[9];
    int a=9;
    int c=0;
    int space[a];
    while(c < a) {
      if(b1s==HIGH) {
        x1[c]==c+1;
        x2[c]==0;
        x3[c]==0;
        x4[c]==0;
        c++;
      }
      else if(b2s==HIGH) {
        x1[c]==0;
        x2[c]==c+1;
        x3[c]==0;
        x4[c]==0;
        c++;
      }
      else if(b3s==HIGH) {
        x1[c]==0;
        x2[c]==0;
        x3[c]==c+1;
        x4[c]==0;
        c++;
      }
      else if(b4s==HIGH) {
        x1[c]==0;
        x2[c]==0;
        x3[c]==0;
        x4[c]==c+1;
        c++;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Is the user initially inputting the desired lock combination and this information is received as char?

Comment: its like, when you use the function to set new password (its button 4, after you log in), you can make any combination of those 4 buttons, up to 8 times, that means you can set b1 b2 b1 b3 b2 b4 b3 et

Comment: why not using a single array to store the password? That would be easier. `[ 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4 ,3, 1 ]` The array itself stores the order and button of the sequence. You could store them as `uint8_t` as that's the minimum required length. If you want i can write the answer for this, and other things you will have to consider for button pressing.

Answer (score 0):

The more elegant code would be:

```
int main() {
    int x[4][9];
    //...
    passwordCreate(x);
    //...
    return(0);
}

void passwordCreate(int x[4][9]) {
    int i;
    int a=9;
    int c=0;
    int space[a];
    while(c < a) {
        for (i=0; i<4; i++)x[i][c]= 0;
        if     (b1s==HIGH) x[0][c]= ++c;
        else if(b2s==HIGH) x[1][c]= ++c;
        else if(b3s==HIGH) x[2][c]= ++c;
        else if(b4s==HIGH) x[3][c]= ++c;
    }
}
```

(And use `=` for assignment, not `==`.)

(EDIT: shown how to call and return the array.)

Note: there is an infinite loop if all the bIs are low.

Note: only one of the bIs may be high at any time (any next bIs being high will be ignored)

Comment: Replace `=c+1;` with `=++c` seems better. Here your are increasing `c` even if all `bXs` are `LOW`

Comment: `int passwordCreate(int x[4][9])`, so pass the array in the call.

Comment: so I can make like
int newPassword = passwordCreate();

and in the function I can write
return(x[4][9]); 

???

Comment: Michael, see my edited version for how to "return" the array (that is, you don't have to as you passed it in the call already).

Comment: okay. So now, if I want to work with that array in main, how do I call it? Like whats the name of returned array? x[#][#]? am I right? and one more question, can I compare whole arrays? Like if they are all the same?

Comment: Michael, I suggest you take a couse in C. Your questions are too basic. I don't mind helping people out, but the people should do their homework. Take a course in C and study books. Bye.

Comment: Michal, to help you along: you are passing a _reference_ to the array `x` declared in `main()` to `createPassword()` so when `createPassword()` is done, you can just access the array `x` in main. `createPasword()` has just modified it. (A reference in C is called _a pointer_.)